# Pass Javascript GetElementById Variable to Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

How to pass Javascript Variable to Ajax and then post it to php. The Javacript code and PHP Code is working fine but problem is passing Javascript Variable to Ajax for posting to PHP. My code is below

```
<!-- User Location --> 
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var startPos;

    var geoSuccess = function(position) {
        startPos = position;
        document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
        document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude; 

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'MyDashboard.php', 
            data: 'latitude='+latitude+'&longitude='+longitude, 
            success: function(msg) { 
                if (msg) { 
                    $("#location").html(msg); 
                } else { 
                    $("#location").html('Not Available'); 
                } 
            } 
        });
    };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
};
</script>
```

Comment: You haven't defined variables for `latitude ` or `longitude`. Check your browser dev tools console for errors thrown

Comment: How to do it? That is what I want actualy

Comment: @AlbertN.Ntshalintshali well you get it correctly when you set the innerHTML....

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what u're asking 
but just

`` data:`latitude=${startPos.coords.latitude}&longitude=${startPos.coords.longitude}` ``

Answer (score 0):

You should pass data as an object like `data: {latitude: latitude, longitude:longitude }`

```
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var startPos;
    var geoSuccess = function(position) {
      startPos = position;
      document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = startPos.coords.latitude;
      document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = startPos.coords.longitude;

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'MyDashboard.php',
        data: {latitude: startPos.coords.latitude, longitude: startPos.coords.longitude },
        success: function(msg) {

          if (msg) {
            $("#location").html(msg);
          } else {
            $("#location").html('Not Available');
          }
        }

      });
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
  };
</script>
```

and get in the php code like `$_POST['latitude']` and `$_POST['longitude']`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `latitude` and `longitude` variable is not exist..

Try below code:

```
<!-- User Location -->
<script>
  window.onload = function() {
    var geoSuccess = function(position) {
      document.getElementById('startLat').innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
      document.getElementById('startLon').innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'MyDashboard.php',
        data: 'latitude=' + position.coords.latitude+ '&longitude=' + position.coords.latitude,
        success: function(msg) {

          if (msg) {
            $("#location").html(msg);
          } else {
            $("#location").html('Not Available');
          }
        }

      });
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geoSuccess);
  };
</script>
```

and retrieve the variable on PHP side by calling these variables `$_POST['latitude']` and `$_POST['longitude']`

Answer (score 0):

You're passing undefined variables. Please try this :

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'MyDashboard.php',
    data: {
      latitude: startPos.coords.latitude,
      longitude: startPos.coords.longitude
    },
    success: function(msg) {

    // your logic

});
```

Answer (score -2):

your send the wrong data to AJAX  POST Method

data: { 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude }

where as your sending AJAX

data: 'latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude,

or  you can add them at URL

url: 'MyDashboard.php?latitude=' + latitude + '&longitude=' + longitude

this will also work  but $_GET need to used in  php instead $_POST

Comment: Nothing inherently wrong with passing a string to `data`. Yes an object is easier but `$.ajax` will handle both